# Why does assigning a variable to itself in a Dom Object make a difference

Tags: javascript, html, variable-assignment

I have a HTML String, called tinymceToHTML in my example and I had the problem that when I download this html String the images sources or hrefs were set wrongly.

My image sources looked like "/file/:id" in the original String, if I convert it into a DOM object and output the source it looks like "http://localhost:3000/file:id" which is the desired output, because then the external document can load this file. So I came up with this solution.

```js
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = tinymceToHTML;
        var images = div.getElementsByTagName('img');
        for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
          images[i].src = images[i].src;
        }
        var a = div.getElementsByTagName('a');
        for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
          a[i].href = a[i].href;
        }
        tinymceToHTML = "<html><head></head><body>" + div.innerHTML +
                        "</body></html>";
```

My problem is that I don't know why assigning the variable to itself makes a difference in that scenario: images[i].src = images[i].src or a[i].href = a[i].href.

If I let the program show me the output with an alarm Box it tells me the URL I want, but without that assignment the program doesn't do what it should.

I hope that anybody can explain me that effect, in order to change maybe the code to make it more clear that this line is required.

**I also created a fiddle example that makes it easier to show what I mean, comment out the line with the assignment, to see the other result**

https://jsfiddle.net/1vabgubh/5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full URL of an image is just what imageElement.src returns, by definition. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement):

> **HTMLImageElement.src** Is a DOMString that reflects the src HTML
>   attribute, containing the full URL of the image including base URI.

If that's how you need them to come out in your final string, then `images[i].src = images[i].src` seems a reasonable and succinct way of doing it. I would just add a comment to aid understanding, something like

```
images[i].src = images[i].src; // force the src to be the full URI
```

Comment: Thank you very much, yes I wanted to avoid doing nonsense and other developers if there will be somebody who will maintain the program, will just delete it or something like that :).

I will use the comment you gave me for the source code.